# Meaning of if statement without == operator

Tags: matlab, if-statement

If `a = 5` and the variable `fl = 0`, what happens in the following case?

```
if fl
   if a < 10
      a = a + 1
   else
      a = a - 1
   end
end
```

I don't understand what the `if fl` part means. I read that as `if 0` or `if false`. That doesn't really mean anything to me. `if fl == 0` would make more sense to me.

So what does `if fl` mean?

Comment: If the value of `fl` is `true` then the statements under `if` will be executed. Otherwise not. It is same as `fl==1`.

Comment: `if fl` is equivalent to `if fl ~= 0`. So if fl = 0 and a = 5 then there will be no change to the variable `a` as the program will not enter the `if fl` block

Comment: One way to find out what happens is typing the program in the MATLAB editor and then stepping through the code line by line. The editor has a big "step" button at the top. You'll see exactly which lines get executed, and it will help you reason about the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it in MATLAB when fl = 0, nothing happens, showing that 0 means false. If you change fl to anything but 0 then the code executes and would print out whatever code is in the if, for the case of a = 5 it would print a = 6

Answer (score 2):

**The condition `if x` in Matlab is equivalent to `if all(logical(x)) == true`**

So let's unpack `all(logical(x))`

- `logical(x)`: We can see this operation is happening because of the error in the below test. So `x` must be something numerical (or a character array which Matlab treats as ASCII values)

  ```
  if 1;       disp('test'); end  % >> displays 'test'
  if [1 2];   disp('test'); end  % >> displays 'test'
  if 'hi';    disp('test'); end  % >> displays 'test', as int8('hi') = [104 105]
  if table(); disp('test'); end  % >> displays error 'Conversion to logical from table 
                                 %                    is not possible'
  ```
- `all(logical(x))`: This means that if `x` is an array then all elements must evaluate to `true`. We can test this is the case by using a couple of examples:

  ```
  if [true true];  disp('test'); end % >> displays 'test'
  if [true false]; disp('test'); end % >> displays nothing
  if [1 0];        disp('test'); end % >> displays nothing
  ```

If you want to write clearer, more maintainable code, then it is often better to be explicit and use `if all(logical(x)) == true`. It's more obvious what's happening when you read the code back, and will make you think about how operations like `any` could be used to achieve different results.

In your example, if `fl = 0` then `all(logical(fl)) = false`, so you never enter the `if` condition.